# Custom redirection in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm trying to build a two-step custom registration for users in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. This involves redirecting users after registration to the Edit view in the User Controller. I've tweaked the code in the stock Account Controller template to achieve this.

```
 public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "User",  new { id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId });
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }


            return View(model);
        }
```

However when I run this I get a 404 on the address bar it shows

```
http://localhost:17005/User/Edit/-1
```

Which means it's going into the Edit action of user controller, but then ending up with a Id of -1. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

Alternatively you could not pass a user id to the edit action and have the code use the currently logged in user.

```
RedirectToAction("Edit", "User");
```

In your user controller

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    object userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
}
```

Please excuse brevity as I am currently on my mobile

Comment: Wow this seems to work great thanks. However I'm not sure if I did it in the best possible way.